# HDF5 input dataset usage in NVIDIA DIGITS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I am new with using NVIDIA DIGITS. My train dataset has following structure and its format is **.hdf5**  .

> ```
> crops       Dataset {27482, 3, 128, 192}
> labels      Dataset {27482, 12}
> mean        Dataset {3, 128, 192}
> pids        Dataset {27482}
> ```

I know how to feed model with simpler formats like .txt or .jpg. My question is how can i feed my model with .hdf5 format in ***NVIDIA DIGITS***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 datasets are only used for image classification datasets in DIGITS, and even then the support isn't very full-featured.

Why?

Caffe doesn't support HDF5 nearly as well as it supports LMDBs:

- For large datasets, you have to break them up into separate files ([see here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2953#issuecomment-136218827))
- Data is not prefetched - the whole dataset is read into memory at once ([see here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1470#issuecomment-72295182))
- Data transformations are not supported with the HDF5Data layer ([see here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2840#issue-98378300))

Since DIGITS is primarily Caffe-based for now, our main dataset format is LMDB. If/when we support more backend frameworks, we may decide to standardize on a more generic format like HDF5 or zipfiles.